# Bases in non-separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is there a systematic way to construct a nondenumerable basis in a nonseparable Hilbert space starting from a non-zero vector?  How are two nondenumerable bases of vectors of norm 1 related to each other in a nonseparable Hilbert space? Examples and pointers to literature would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The usual method is to use the axiom of choice. I'm not sure it would be possible without it.